# Can't access dataframe columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, removing-whitespace

I'm importing a dataframe from a csv file, but cannot access some of it's columns by name. What's going on?

In more concrete terms:

```
> import pandas

> jobNames = pandas.read_csv("job_names.csv")
> print(jobNames)

   job_id   job_name   num_judgements
0  933985        Foo              180
1  933130        Moo              175
2  933123        Goo              150
3  933094       Flue              120
4  933088        Tru              120
```

When I try to access the second column, I get an error:

```
> jobNames.job_name
```

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'job_name'

Strangely, I can access the job_id column thus:

```
> print(jobNames.job_id)

0    933985
1    933130
2    933123
3    933094
4    933088
Name: job_id, dtype: int64
```

**Edit (to put the accepted answer in context):**

It turns out that the first row of the csv file (with the column names) looks like this:

```
job_id, job_name, num_judgements
```

Note the spaces after each comma! Those spaces are retained in the column names:

```
> jobNames.columns[1]

' job_name'
```

which don't form valid python identifiers, so those columns aren't available as dataframe attributes. I can still access them dict-style:

```
> jobNames[' job_name']
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) pass in `skipinitialspace=True` flag to remove whitespace after CSV delimiters.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution for removing whitespaces from column names is [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
jobNames.columns = jobNames.columns.str.strip()
print (jobNames.job_name)

0     Foo
1     Moo
2     Goo
3    Flue
4     Tru
```

Answer (score 0):

Another (perhaps inferior) approach is to remove the spaces from the column names:

```
> jobNames.columns = map(lambda s:s.strip(), jobNames.columns)
> jobNames.job_name

0   Foo
1   Moo
2   Goo
3   Flue
4   Tru
Name: job_name, dtype: object
```