# Pandas Dataframe has inaccesible Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an extraordinary weird bug.
There is a csv file that I read, it contains 2 columns: "Column" and "NA_Value".
I am reading the file with pandas. Both columns are accesible via df.column or df.keys() but I can not access the column with the name "Column" in any way. Also renaming did not help.

[image: Full Bug in action]

Comment: what happens if you try `df["Column"]`?

Comment: Probably some sort of encoding issue. Try reading your csv and naming the columns explicitly: `pd.read_csv(..., names=["Column", "NA_Value"]`.

Comment: @DrPrettyman same bug

Comment: It seems there is a solution for you here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894098/cant-access-dataframe-columns

Comment: @SerahsiSen That post suggests that the column in question here has a name with a leading space and that does not appear to be the case here.

Comment: Can you include a sample of data from the csv

Comment: If your csv file is saved with utf-8 and a byte order mark and you open it with a default encoding of utf-8 you will replicate this error. Check to make sure your actual and expected encodings match. Note Excel likes to toss in the BOM when saving as "utf-8" ...

Answer (score 0):

run all cells. this should work.
else why not try : df['Column']